# NodeJS Reverse Proxy for Jetty

Tags: node.js, proxy, jetty, reverse-proxy

I have a single server running jetty as a web server.  I run a proxy server at port `80` to decide whether a request is made for jetty or static file server using nodejs.  My jetty is running at port `9000` and the other static file server is running at `9001`.  Here is my node proxy code;

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var options = {
  hostnameOnly : true,
  router : {
    'domain.com' : '127.0.0.1:9000',
    'static.domain.com' : '127.0.0.1:9001'
  }
}

var proxyServer = httpProxy.createServer(options).listen(80);
```

When I request a page from `domain.com` it gives me this error;

`{ code: 'ECONNREFUSED', errno: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect' }`

It is supposed to redirect the request to jetty but it just does not, couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jetty config allowed ip for connections was the outer IP address of the server, I changed it to 127.0.0.1 and it worked.